# How to draw cement-wall-like transition background in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, background

I would like to draw how shadow decays on plaster-like wall in Adobe Illustrator, like this

[image]

Is it possible to do with Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

Textures like these are mostly bitmaps and, hence, better done with Photoshop or another bitmap editor.

Creating textures is possible within Illustrator using the different Photoshop effects in the `Effect` menu. But, as the name suggests, these are not vector effects. And it's not easy to achieve the effect you want if it isn't in the default effects.

A way better method of using textures is to actually obtain pixel images, edit them in Photoshop and then place (or paste) them into Illustrator. You can shoot the images yourself as photographs, or rely on stock images. One image bank I keep on returning to is [CGtextures](http://cgtextures.com/), which has a huge collection of royalty-free images originally meant for use in constructing 3D environments.

In the case you give, you'd want to add to add a gradient to the texture. This can be done by creating an object on top of the texture, giving that a gradient and setting its blending mode to `Myltiply`, `Color Burn` or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we can get this kind of effect in illustrator but it will be much easier to do in Adobe Photoshop. (Add a new layer or Shift + Ctrl + N. Then go to Filter>Render>Clouds to create cloudy effect).

Comment: I'm not sure if the steps described are sufficient to get the effect that is asked. It is not explained how to achieve the gradient. Could you please elaborate your answer? Additionally the answer is not a place for self-advertisement. Your [profile](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/37201/digiscape-gallery) is, but I see that you already filled that in.

Comment: As @BartArondson says, please refrain from self-promotion beyond your profile, or you might get smap infractions. That said, please elaborate a bit on your technique. You're pointing in the right direction, but a bit more explanation down the road (hehe) would make a good answer! Thanks.